# How to import all your components, styles, etc. using 'import component from src/*' in React with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try one of the following two imports

```
import 'src/assets/styles/App.scss'
-
import 'assets/styles/App.scss'
```

I'm receiving the following error's respectively

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'src/assets/styles/App.scss' in '/path/to/my/project/src'
-
Module not found: Can't resolve 'assets/styles/App.scss' in '/path/to/my/project/src'
```

---

In typescript I believe that I was fixing this by having

```
"include": [
    "./src/**/*"
]
```

in my tsconfig.json, either that or maybe

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure completely sure though, because these options were created by create-react-app

---

How would I create this effect in just plain javascript in React?

---

**Update**

I created a jsconfig.json file containing

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {   
        "baseUrl": "./",   
    }
}
```

and receive the following error output

```js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
        throw err;
        ^
    
    SyntaxError: /path/to/my-app/jsconfig.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 62
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:27)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at getModules (/path/to/my-app//node_modules/react-scripts/config/modules.js:133:14)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/config/modules.js:149:18)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2020-09-22T17_18_27_953Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're using Webpack, edit your `webpack.config.js` with:

```
resolve: {
   alias: {
     assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
     components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/')
    }
}
```

In case not, you could use a **Babel** plugin called [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver).
To activate this plugin functionality, create the file `.babelrc`, or edit in case you already have it with this code:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      alias: {
        assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/')
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

This code will define the alias of the paths assets & components. Then, you can use them to import directly as per your example:

```
import * as assets from 'assets/myModule'
```

- [Babel documentation](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/blob/master/DOCS.md).
- [Good examples of using this plugin](https://gist.github.com/nodkz/41e189ff22325a27fe6a5ca81df2cb91).

Comment: And this works with `create-react-app`  or with I have to export it?

Comment: yes, it does, as long you install the library and configure it. Also, I've added docs links so it is easy to troubleshoot anything

Comment: Why the babel module resolver? I was able to achieve this effect by just adding `resolve: {alias: {assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/')}}` to my `webpack.config.js`

Comment: That's the second option in case you aren't using Webpack. I mentioned the babel plugin because there wasn't any clue about using Webpackc in your question, and this might help other people with the same problem.

Comment: I see, I wasn’t using web pack when I started the question, sorry

Comment: No worries at all. I will edit my question to add your info when using webpack, so it is more complete. Is that okay? (with credits of course)

Answer (score 0):

Try  with creating a  .env file that contains :
NODE_PATH=src/

Comment: exactly like that? Should src be in quotes or something?

Comment: I received a warning that that is deprecated in favour of specifying the baseUrl in `jsconfig.json`

Comment: Yeah in the root folder of react app create a .env file and inside this file write  : NODE_PATH=src/